# How to write convert an anonymous functions to a regular function while using use $variable

Tags: php, arrays, array-map

I'm trying to figure out how to convert the array_map portion with the anonymous function to just a function while using the use function to be able to support php 5.2 but i keep getting an error. Here is my current code.

```
<?php

$collection = array();

$op_field = array(
    'fname' => 'sarmen',
    'lname' => 'b',
    'age' => 33,
    'gender' => 'male'
);

$nf_field = array(
    'type' => 'human',
    'age' => 30,
    'gender' => 'male',
    'ethnicity' => 'american'
);



array_map(function($op, $nf) use (&$collection)
{
    $collection[] = array(
        'op' => $op,
        'nf' => $nf
    );
}, $op_field, $nf_field);


print_r($collection);
```

I've tried

```
function mapping($op, $nf)
{
    $collection[] = array(
        'op' => $op,
        'nf' => $nf
    );
    return $collection;
}

array_map(mapping($op, $nf), use ($&collection), $op_field, $nf_field);
```

But that just gives a parse error. Any idea on how it would be written? I really appreciate it.

Comment: You can't use `use` in 5.2.

Comment: How else can i achieve what i'm trying to do with php 5.2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to pass in a reference to `$collection`, instead just do the following:

```
function mapping($op, $nf)
{
    return array(
        'op' => $op,
        'nf' => $nf
    );
}

$collection = array_map('mapping', $op_field, $nf_field);
```

Yields:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [op] => sarmen
            [nf] => human
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [op] => b
            [nf] => 30
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [op] => 33
            [nf] => male
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [op] => male
            [nf] => american
        )

)
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

First off you have to pass the callback as string when you want to use a normal function. Second there is no `use` before PHP 5.3, so you would have to use global.

And if you put everything together you will get:

```
function callbackFunction($op, $nf){
    global $collection;

    $collection[] = array(
        'op' => $op,
        'nf' => $nf
    );
}

array_map("callbackFunction", $op_field, $nf_field);
```

Comment: Can someone please explain the downvote to a correct answer? So I can change my answer.

Comment: No idea, wasn't me! And yes, this is a correct answer.

Comment: i will bring balance to the force ... but really you have never encountered random down votes before? (I do it all the time bahahahahaha)

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd say it's because you used a `global`. I've had similar downvotes for suggesting a *Singleton* was a good solution for a particular problem

Comment: @Phil Maybe. Just wanted to show step by step what to change out with what to make it compatible for PHP < 5.3